# Validação com AJAX no Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, validação, laravel-5.3

Fala pessoal, gostaria de saber como fazer validações com o AJAX no laravel, já tentei de varias formas e não funciona, não posto o codigo porque tinha desistido ai não tenho mais rsrs... mas gostaria de aprender. Vocês tem algum tutorial (pode ser em inglês) com exemplos de controller, view e script, sendo requisição POST. Desde já, obg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução, um tutorial muito bom e que funciona de verdade no Laravel 5.3

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-ajax-request-validation-exampleexample.html